# ¿Como puedo cambiar la orientación de mi FloatingActionMenu? Android Studio

Tags: android, menú

Quiero que los botones se desplacen hacia arriba, intente cambiando la orientación de la pantalla pero el vídeo también gira y ya no se ve en toda la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**ESTE ES EL JAVA:**

```
public class ActivityPrueba extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout ll;
FloatingActionMenu actionMenu;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    actionMenu=(FloatingActionMenu)findViewById(fabPrincipal);
    //actionMenu.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);
    actionMenu.showMenu(true);



    VideoView intro = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView9);
    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.dante.provantf_movil/" + R.raw.controlblanco;
    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    intro.setVideoURI(uri2);
    intro.requestFocus();
    intro.start();

    //  AQUI EMPIEZA EL REPRODUCTOR DE MUSICA UNO
    Button buttonPlayVideo2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnT_Izq_Rot);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
   //displays a video file
    buttonPlayVideo2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView9);
  // VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
            String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.dante.provantf_movil/" + R.raw.trimizq;
            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
            mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
            mVideoView2.requestFocus();
            mVideoView2.start();
        }
    });

}
public void clicSubMenuHome(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityPrueba.this, Principal.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    actionMenu.hideMenu(true);
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Sub Menu Home Tocado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void clicSubMenuActPrueba(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityPrueba.this, ControlRemoto.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    actionMenu.hideMenu(true);
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Sub Menu Home Tocado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

**Y ESTE EL XML:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.dante.provantf_movil.ActivityPrueba"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_prueba">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnJ_Izq"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="141dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fabPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/mas"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    >

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/subMenuActPrueba"
        android:onClick="clicSubMenuActPrueba"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mas2"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/subMenuHome"
        android:onClick="clicSubMenuHome"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home"/>

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Comment: Cual es el link de la documentacion del FloatingActionMenu  que utilizas?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar esta linea al FloattingActionMenu en el xml.

```
 //Para mostrar los botones
 fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"

 //Cuando se ocultan
 fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"

 //La direccion hacia donde se abrirá el menú
 fab:menu_openDirection="up"
```

Prueba y comenta si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Ya probé tu código y no funciona, me sigue apareciendo igual =/

Comment: @Dante Mmm.. ahora intenta agregar esta linea: fab:menu_openDirection="up" creo con eso debería ser suficiente

Comment: No es tan sencillo realizar lo que comenta el OP con una propiedad, se debe crear una clase que muestre los elementos en la orientación requerida.

Answer (score 0):

actualmente estoy trabajando con floating action button. Y estoy utilizando una librería que mencionan en esta página, te dejo el link, está muy completo y al final enseñan como usar el FAB con diferentes menus:
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/02/floating-action-button-android/

Comment: Olvide mencionarte que esa librería por defecto despliega el menú en vertical, tal como quieres.

Comment: Jananhelo, gracias por tu contribución, **debes revisar [answer]. "Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces."**